# image submit button localisation mvc 2

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-2, button, localization, submit

i am trying to create a view page in my MVC2 Application
i have a submit button which is an image (round edged image).
but when i run the application it shows a normal button instead.
the code i used is :

`<input type="submit" value="Log On" id="login_button_75" />`

and the style:

```
#login_button_75 {
    background:url(images/login_submit_button.png) no-repeat;
    height:28px;
    width:75px;
    background-position:center;
}
```

also i need to change the **button value** for localization 
such as "Log On" to "تسجيل دخول".

please help me
thanks,
suraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem of image button.
it was with the problem of registering the css file in the form.

the second one is solved by the following code:

```
<input type="submit" value="<%: GetGlobalResourceObject("Button","LogOn_Submit") %>" class="login_button_75" />
```

regards,
suraj

Answer (score 0):

You could use [resources](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html) to localize your application. And here's another [example](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Localization.aspx).